# How Symfony2 know where are sass and compass installed?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have installed Sass, and Compass using:

```
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

And now I'm trying to integrate Sass, Compass with Assetic on symfony2. But what I don't understand is *How Symfony2 does to find the Sass and Compass instalations on my system (Windows 8)* ?

Comment: You mean, *does it know*? Or are you asking *will it know*, or *why doesn't it know*?

Comment: Sorry English isn't my first lang. I think I mean If Symfony2 need to know where Sass and Compass were installed, the paths to binaries ie. But it's answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the path to the executable as part of your assetic config, this is covered in the docs;

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html

Comment: Awesome! :D *Autonote:* Ever ever ever see the configuration references of sf2 docs before asking xD Thanks!!